# c++ windows get Usb port and hub by USB serial

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb

I'm trying to capture video from usb webcam, what is connected to a certain usb port (I have many same cameras connected). I have a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426644/directshow-capture-to-file-nothing-happens) that makes USB Device Path for all webcams. I have something like:

```
\\?\usb#vid_0c45&pid_614a#5&18f54cb7&0&2#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global
```

Where: 5&18f54cb7&0&2 - USB serial string. I cant use pid and vid because I have other same webcams.

How can I get usb port and hub knowing USB serial?

Comment: No idea why this is called too broad. USB hubs form a tree starting at root hubs (which are on your motherboard or possibly a PCI-e card), and Windows knows that tree

Answer (score 1):

The hub is the parent of the webcam, so you find it via `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` property `DEVPKEY_Device_Parent`. USB port is `DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo`.